# Captcha alternative

Tags: captcha, user-experience

In order to implement a CAPTCHA for my login page, I would like to understand how a translation test can be considered secure compared to popular image recognition patterns.

All customers will be bilingual speakers of an orally learnt and used Polynesian language i.e., no formal spelling conventions (hence the translation to English not the reverse), so instead of asking them to read distorted letters I would like to ask them to translate a simple sentence into English to be validated from the PHP server side.

Is this secure/accurate?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "safe"? A bot would have to know what you were asking users to do, so while I think it's unlikely there are many spambot crawlers out there that would understand "translate this [from Polynesian] into English" it's certainly possible for somebody to write a script that specifically targets the site and does so.

Comment: Define safe, it depends on what you want to achieve; _Will it stop some bots from misusing your system?_ **Yes.** _Will it stop all of them?_ **No.**  Another thing to be aware of is how strict your check of the translation should be, how to capital letters? Special signs? Simple typo? There are many factors to remember to take notice off. **The more strict you make it, the more "secure" it will become, but also more annoying for your users**

Comment: It needs to be an exact match, so that's as strict as possible, basically I read a lot about forms being attacked and I want to secure mine from random attack as much as possible. Annoying isn't a problem, people so far prefer it. But it's not a live system yet.

Comment: I retract my close vote but suggest to move this to Security SE. I would like to contribute by rephrasing the question not to be too broad or opinion based

Comment: Many Polynesian languages for example Niuean will NEVER be on google translate. it's barely documented with a wordlist of 1500 words. It has about 2000 speakers Worldwide and will be extinct next generation. I'm looking for solutions that will work here and now. If it's a race between technology working out how to read captcha pics and Google translate doing my language, I'll bet on the technology beating captcha. It's not Niuean by the way. Apart from google translate what dangers would I face?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments, it seems the only danger I face is a vague future Google Translate one, which is unlikely to eventuate. So I'm going to stick my head out and say that this is indeed a good security measure which could conceivably be useful to many businesses or organisations that have such a customer base. Thanks for the assist.
Major point in it's favor is ease of use for the customers all of which so far prefer it to trying to read captcha. I put it on a live system so had 80+ people use it today.

Answer (score 0):

I presume they all speak English too then? Unusual to require your users to be bilingual. Even if this is the case today, is it possible that with future growth you might be excluding certain users? What if someone moves into the area who wants to signup but only speaks English?

Language is a funny imprecise thing. You could take a sentence and probably translate it a number of different ways. Computers deal in precision so you need a question where there can only be one answer.

Also, the whole idea of a CAPTCHA is to make sure it's a real person but it may not be too hard to write a program that uses google translate or something similar. It may not always get it right but it'd probably get through some of the time.

Comment: no google translate for this language, or most Polynesian languages for that matter, and we're all bilingual, English is mandatory at school. (Some are more bilingual than others)

Comment: It's likely going to be more secure than no captcha but personally I would just go with whats tried and trusted. I still think it will annoy users if their translation isn't an exact match with yours and while there may be no google translate today there may be one in future.

Comment: good point about future possible problems, I'm trying to see any flaws in my logic. Exact match is easy, I put a lot of thought into the questions. But you have pointed out a potential weakness for me, which is what I was wanting.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea to state that this kind of [CAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) ("Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart") is totally insecure is that while the OP states that "currently" Google Translator doesn't offer support for Polynesian language, it cannot be excluded that it will do so in the future.

More generally, translation is not a valid CAPTCHA test because of the following considerations:

- Comparing a random sentence VS its automated translation using a public translator (e.g. a future version of Google, Bing) is equal for a hacker submitting the same phrase to the translation engine
- Using a whitelist of sentences and their translations will be eventually overwhelmed by the accuracy of the automated public translators

I mean that modern public computer translators are perfecting their accuracy. If you assume that a public translator is unable to perform an accurate job today and challenge the user with a known phrase the translator cannot process, technology will tend to eventually fix that translation and you will get the challenge sentence easily spotted by robots.

That is the main principle of ReCaptcha being used as an OCR, but from the opposite side. I will suggest you to read [this paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~biglou/reCAPTCHA_Science.pdf) but briefly the researchers state that ReCaptcha is destined to improve its accuracy far more than automated OCRs because of user input.

Since Google and Bing Translate widely use user-submitted data to improve their translation process, they will be subject to a human-aided machine learning eventually breaking the Turing Test for that kind of challenge (e.g. ReCaptcha will read like a human, Translate will translate like a human)

Comment: 3 years on and still working great, no sign of this machine translate problem you mentioned and never will be.

Comment: Can you indicate the website you are implementing captcha on? Do you allow some of us to hack you? :)

Comment: In other words, if you are really live with such, it might be that you are the only implementor and yet no one has tried to bypass. Yet...

Comment: not going to let devs hack it, but if you can tell me the English meaning of pepesto soo, I'll believe you could do it through the password and not other ways.

Comment: If that is Samoan... "often populated"? Google Translator said this

Comment: nope, not even close. I actually speak Samoan as well, but no idea how google got populated... even often is just one possibility. Polynesian languages are contextual